# Where is the Task Manager?

Tags: task-management

Is there any UI in ubuntu like the one in Windows to kill the processes forcefully.

My google chrome application is stuck and i can't close it, need to do it forcefully.Please help !

Comment: Look at how many times this question has been viewed. Something isn't quite intuitive enough in Ubuntu

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Yes, there is a gui. If installed, you can start it with

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

If not installed, you can either search in the Software Center for System monitor or type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor
```

Hope this helps.

Or, to make it a bit easier, just open the dash and type *System Monitor*.

Answer (score 36):

Open the Dash and search for system monitor. There you can stop the processes you want easily