# How do I properly restart Chrome?

Tags: process, task-management

I've been doing some WebGL development, and of course crashing Chrome occasionally along the way.

When this happens, WebGL in Chrome won't work until I restart my PC, which makes me think that even though I close every Chrome window I can see, it's still running somehow.

In Windows I am used to using task manager to ensure an application has actually stopped running, what's the Ubuntu equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: [This thread on super user may be helpful](http://superuser.com/questions/131019/killing-all-instances-of-chrome-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Addressing the question title : Chrome has a special URL *`chrome://restart`* and I think that is quite platform-independent :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```bash
killall chrome
# or
pkill -9 -f chrome
```

If either of the above don't work, then try adding `sudo`:

```bash
sudo killall chrome
# or
sudo pkill -9 -f chrome
```

Comment: Thank you. `killall chrome` alone, withOUT `sudo`, works fine for me! I didn't even have to try `pkill -9 -f chrome`.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI for this is `gnome-system-monitor` (see [Wolf F.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/224932/187281) to [Where is the Task Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224931/where-is-the-task-manager)).

Or, optionally, you could go the terminal route (open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```bash
ps -ef
kill <process ID of the suspicious process>
```

(Process IDs are the numbers on the left.)

Comment: Furthermore you can use the top command if you prefer using the terminal. The top command lists your CPU tasks and enables you to kill them (like task manager)